# Allow downgrades in WiX with warning message

Tags: windows-installer, wix3.8

Forgive my ignorance, I'm not very knowledgeable with WiX. I have a software that we suddenly need to allow downgrades on. In WiX, it's pretty simple, just set `AllowDowngrades` to yes.

```
<MajorUpgrade   
AllowDowngrades="yes" />
```

However, is there any way to add some kind of pop-up or warning message to let the user know that this will be a downgrade? Then they could choose to cancel or continue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm oversimplifying it but why not just add a custom action in the InstallUISequence that prompts with a messageBox then handle the response?

How are you planning to handle the silent installs where the UISequence does not get run?

Comment: The initial struggle was that users installing silently via command line were not able to downgrade. We want it to be possible, so I switch it to allow downgrades. However if the user is installing normally, I want them to be warned.

Comment: @sondos Did you ever find a solution to this? I would also like to show a warning when the user is downgrading in non-silent mode.